# gunzip multiple gz files with same compressed file name in multiple folders

Tags: command-line, wildcards, zip, gzip, gunzip

I have a directory where there are multiple folders, each folder contains multiple .gz files with the same zipped file name "spark.log". How can I unzip all of them at once and rename them like the gz file?

My data looks like this

List of folders

```
A
B
C
D
```

In every of them there are files as

```
A
spark.log.gz
spark.log.1.gz
spark.log.2.gz
spark.log.3.gz
B
spark.log.gz
spark.log.1.gz
spark.log.2.gz
spark.log.3.gz
C
spark.log.gz
spark.log.1.gz
spark.log.2.gz
spark.log.3.gz
D
spark.log.gz
spark.log.1.gz
spark.log.2.gz
spark.log.3.gz
```

in each of the gz file contains `spark.log`, I'd like to be able to unzip and rename them according to their gz name. For example:
`spark.log.1.gz` -> `spark.log.1.log`

Comment: If you are uncompressing the logs so that you can search them, keep in mind that there are tools like `zcat` and `zgrep` that can read gzipped files without having to first uncompress them.

Comment: Using `gunzip` on `spark.log.2.gz` would give you `spark.log.2`, which is the name of the file that was compressed. I don't quite see why you want to add an _extra_ `.log` to the end of that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `gzip` does or can store the original name, which you can reveal  by running `gzip -Nl file.gz`:

```
$ gzip spark.log
$ mv spark.log.gz spark.log.1.gz
$ gzip -l spark.log.1.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                170                 292  51.4% spark.log.1
$ gzip -lN spark.log.1.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                170                 292  51.4% spark.log
```

`gunzip` will not use that for the name of the uncompressed file unless you pass the `-N` option and will just use the name of the gzipped file with the `.gz` suffix removed.

You may be confusing it with Info-ZIP's `zip` command and its related `zip` format which is a compressed archive format while gzip is just a compressor like `compress`, `bzip2`, `xz`...

So you just need to call `gunzip` without `-N` on those files:

```
gunzip -- */spark.log*.gz
```

And you'll get `spark.log`, `spark.log.1`, `spark.log.2`... (not `spark.log.1.log` which wouldn't make sense, nor `spark.1.log`, which could be interpreted as a log file for a `spark.1` service as opposed to the most recent rotation of `spark.log`).

Having said that, there's hardly ever any reason to want to uncompress log files. Accessing the contents is generally quicker when they are compressed. Modifying the contents is potentially more expensive, but you generally don't modify log files after they've been archived / rotated.  You can use `zgrep`, `vim`, `zless` (even `less` if configured to do so) to inspect their contents. `zcat -f ./*.log*(nOn) | grep...` if using `zsh` to send all the logs from older to newer to `grep`, etc.

Comment: great explanation, though the reason why i'd like to have .log extension is because I'm using mac os and I'd like to be able to click on the .log files to view them, rather than typing it out in terminal. So I suppose my question should be in mac stackexchange to see if there's an app that can view gzipped log files.

Answer (score 1):

This `bash` script should do what you want:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

for file in ./*/*.gz; do
      newfile="${file/%.gz/.log}"
      printf 'Extracting %s to %s\n' "$file" "$newfile"

      gzip -dc "$file" > "$newfile"
      # Use this instead if the .gz file should be deleted
      # gzip -dc "$file" > "$newfile" && rm "$file"
done
```

You have to be in the path where you have your folders `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`, etc...

The line: `newfile="${file/%.gz/.log}"` assigns the new name of the file that will be renamed (e.g. *spark.log.1.log* should be the new filename if the `gz` file is *spark.log.1.gz*)
With `${file/%.gz/.log}` I'm replacing the `.gz` at the end of the current file.

The `printf` statement is not necessary but could be useful if you want see a detailed output about what's happening in each iteration.

Using `gzip -dc` with a redirection means this will work without having to worry about the name of the extracted file.